# Importing Data with Line feeds

Tags: import, character-encoding

I am trying to import data from a CSV file into Mathematica that contains *line feeds* in certain elements that I wish to be properly rendered in Mathematica. I suppose this has something to do with the type of form (InputForm, StandardForm, etc.) that Mathematica uses on and after import. I know I am missing something fundamental but have not found it yet.

I do not want the solution to this problem to contain any Mathematica code in the CSV file.

Lets take graph labels as an example.

[image]

I would like one vertex label to have *two* on the first line and *deux* on the second line. I have tried entering the data in various ways with no success. Here is what I have tried.

1. two[LineFeed]deux

**Result**: is shown above. There IS a linefeed but the control code name is also rendered.

2. two\ndeux

**Result**: No line feed at all.

[image]

3. two.0Adeux (i.e. using hexadecimal code)

Result: Same as [NewLine], get the line feed but the hex code is printed too.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Jeff Lapides

Comment: Possibly a bug? `ImportString[ExportString[{{1, "long\nthing"}, {2, "other"}}, "CSV", "TextDelimiters" -> "\""],"CSV", "TextDelimiters" -> "\""]` returns `{{"1,\"long"}, {"thing\""}, {2, "other"}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your CSV has the following format, with vertices in column 1 and vertexlabels in column 2.

```
1   one\nun
2   two\ndeux
3   three\ntrois
4   four\nquatre
5   five\ncinq
6   six\nsix
```

I think the following might work:

```
labels = Import["label.csv"];
Graph[{1 -> 3, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 4}, 
 VertexLabels -> 
  Map[#[[1]] -> StringReplace[#[[2]], "\\n" -> "\n"] &, labels], 
 ImagePadding -> 25]
```

[image: graph with labels]

It looks like the `Import` command will escape the `\n` and you need to unescape it with a `StringReplace`.

Comment: This looks great. I will check it out tomorrow. Thank you very much.

Jeff

Comment: Bob:
I just checked this out and it works great. I tested on my test data set. Will check on the production one next.
Thanks Again.